# Using Condition in BIDS Helper

Tags: excel, ssas, powerpivot, dax, bids

I have a power pivot linked to an SSAS cube. I want to have an action menu on pivot to show the detail (like Drill Through) but with a specific `filter`.

I define the `Action Type` as `Drill Through` and add a DAX/MDX statement in `Condition` input box. However there is no error in my DAX formula, it breaks action menu in Excel and doesn't show the menu.

I have tried below formulas:

```
"filter('rptLoanExpiringEligibility', [RemainingDaysToPoolMBS] <= 10)"
```

and this one

```
[RemainingDaysToPoolMBS] <= 10
```

Is there anyone who has used the Condition for action?
Is there any alternate to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Action Type to Rowset. Change Target Type to Cells. Change Condition to true. Set Expression to:

```
"filter('rptLoanExpiringEligibility', [RemainingDaysToPoolMBS] <= 10)"
```

There are a few examples [here](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tabular%20Actions%20Editor&referringTitle=Documentation) that are slightly different.